# Git Clone QT5 Gitorious

Tags: git, qt5, gitorious

I can't clone QT5 from gitorious anymore. This used to work:

git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git --branch v5.3.1 --single-branch 5_3_1_x64_msvc2012

Now the command above returns with error:
"fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Unfortunatly the Qt wiki page is down.
https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

I know gitorious was recently bought by Gitlab but on their blog they claim it does not affect existing projects.

http://blog.gitorious.org/

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Changing it to `https://` instead of `git://` worked for me for this project: https://gitorious.org/svg2latex/svg2latex?p=svg2latex:svg2latex.git;a=summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a Qt 5 project on Github:

https://github.com/qtproject/qt5

```
git clone https://github.com/qtproject/qt5.git --branch v5.3.1 --single-branch 5_3_1_x64_msvc2012
```

If you're unsure about the integrity of the code, you can compare the tree SHA-1 of your new clone with a reference one that you have already cloned some time ago (since you stated you 'usually' do this I assume you have a copy somewhere).

To do this, start by comparing the commit SHA-1 of the `v5.3.1` branch:

```
cd 5_3_1_x64_msvc2012
git rev-parse --short HEAD    # returns fb1c991
git cat-file -p fb1c991
```

The last command will return the content of the blob representing the latest commit of the v5.3.1 branch you have just cloned. It should return some text, starting with:

```
tree e187f2fafb6e478f4e6a0ce65e5f4bba7a224269
...
```

That `e187f2fafb6e` must be identical to your reference one if you repeat the same process on an existing clone. This guarantees the mirror is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

God bless Google page caching. The offline QT wiki mentions also this repository:

git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git